# Next Line on iPhone only

Tags: word-wrap, line-breaks

I have this in a footer. It workes great with all formats except in an iPhone in portrait.
(Obviously I've change the actual company wording)

> Something Group work in association with Another Company Sales Limited

On the iPhone I would like to keep the company name togeter on the one line.

So instead of:

> Something Group work in association with Another 
> Company Sales Limited

I would have:

> Something Group work in association with Another Company Sales Limited

Can I do this on the iPhone portrait only, and leave ever other devices as is?

Comment: Should iPhone portrait mode just decrease the size of the font until the entire line fits as a single line? Also: is the footer its own view? If so, which class?

Comment: Thanks Tommy.
Unfortunately the line is too long to achieve that, but your suggestion has given my an idea of doing the opposite. This would force the word I need to the next line.

Comment: Naive question: have you tried just using non-breaking spaces in the proper spots?